# Compilation Error Error: no mixin named breakpoint-down

Tags: javascript, html, css, mixins, scss-mixins

I created a mixin css file

```css
//Breakpoint
@media (min-width: 64em) {
    //styles go here
}
//640px, 1024px, 1400px
$breakpoints-up: ("medium": "40em", "large": "64em", "xlarge": "87.5em");

// 639px, 1023px, 139px
$breakpoints-down: ("small": "39.9375em", "medium": "63.9375em", "large": "87.4375em");

@mixin breakpoint-up($size) {
    @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints-up, $size)) {
        @content;
    }
}
@mixin breakpoint-down($size) {
    @media (max-width: map-get($breakpoints-down, $size)) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

and then i tried to implement it in my global css file

```css
.hide-for-mobile {
    //Hide for tab and mobile
    @include breakpoint-down(medium) {
        display: none;
    }
}

.hide-for-desktop {
    //hide for desktop
    @include breakpoint-up(large) {
        display: none;
}
}
```

although the global and mixin files are part of the imports in my main css file

```css
@import "globals";
@import "mixins";
@import "variables";
@import "headers";
```

at the end it gives error

```html
Compilation Error
Error: no mixin named breakpoint-down
        on line 63 of sass/c:\Users\USER\Downloads\Project\app\scss\_globals.scss
        from line 1 of sass/c:\Users\USER\Downloads\Project\app\scss\style.scss
>>     @include breakpoint-down(medium) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue might be that you're importing `globals` before you're importing `mixins`. Because of this, at the time globals is called there *isn't* a mixin called `breakpoint-down`: it's not been defined yet. To fix it, you might just need to switch the imports around

```css
@import "mixins"; // First instead of second
@import "globals";
@import "variables";
@import "headers";
```

hope this helped :)